# Adding real-time collaboration to an app

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm creating a scoreboard app and I'd like to add some collaboration functionality. All I need is for users to be able to add other users, and that lets them work on the same scoreboard. Would adding the Real-Time Match Game Center feature to my app give me this functionality, or is there a better way to go about it? I've read up a bit on the [Game Center Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but I hesitate going that route because I want users to be able to add people who aren't on Game Center (without the collaboration feature), and aside from that all the user's saved data is stored locally on the device and I'm not sure how that would be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [SocketIO](http://socket.io/), there's a very good swift library.

From their web page:

> Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication.

SocketIO leaves an open connection so you can send messages to the server, and the server will broadcast to any other user... SocketIO works great with chats and I think is the perfect solution for what you want to do, also SocketIO supports multiple users connected to the "same channel"